# Need to understand the syntax of line_items_path(product_id: product)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through Iteration D3 of Agile Web Development in Rails 4 and I understood most of the code below except for the syntax `line_items_path(product_id: product)`.

I understand that the code allows a product will be created through LineItemsController with reference to the `product_id`.

But I dont understand the syntax of the hash (`product_id: product`) as a parameter of `line_items_path`. why is there `product` after `product_id:`? Is it an overly simplified version of something?

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry">
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
    <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    <%= sanitize(product.description) %>

    <div class="price_line">
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price, unit: '$') %></span>
      <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show us the routes?

Comment: https://github.com/kristianmandrup/awd-rails-4th-depot-app/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
line_items_path({ :product_id => product })
```

In other words, you're passing one argument to the `line_items_path` method. That argument is a Hash. That Hash has a single key, which is the Symbol `:product_id`. The value being associated with that key is the value of the local variable `product` (`product` could also be a method name, but in this case it's the local variable passed to the block given to `@products.each`).

#### Edit

In reply to your comment: When you pass a Hash to a `_url` or `_path` helper, Rails assumes that its keys correspond to the [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) in the route, so if you have a route like `/vendors/:id/products/:product_id`, Rails will fill in `:id` and `:product_id` with the corresponding values from the Hash.

When that value isn't a number or string (or other primitive type), Rails will first try to call the [`to_param`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param) method on it. By default, an ActiveRecord object's `to_param` method will return the object's `id`, so if, for example, `product` is an instance of the Product model and its `id` is `123`, then these four lines would yield the same result:

```
line_items_path(product_id: product)
line_items_path(product_id: product.to_param)
line_items_path(product_id: product.id)
line_items_path(product_id: 123)
```

For more information I recommend reading this answer:
[Where is the documentation on url helpers in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458337/where-is-the-documentation-on-url-helpers-in-rails/17458566#17458566) as well as the absolutely essential [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters).

Comment: is there any difference with line_items_path(product)?

Comment: thanks. understood the syntatic sugar. but wish to understand why is the parameter a hash? as you mentioned product (which a local variable) is a value, how is it a value? the attributes of the product constitute the "value"?

Comment: @RailsNewbie I think I understand your confusion. I've updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Just curious if line_items_path(product.id) will yield the same result? If not, why not? Is it because there is no :controller?

Comment: Yes, I believe it will. When you don't use a hash, the method will fill in the arguments you give it from left to right, so if your route is e.g. `/line_items/:product_id` then the argument you give to `line_items_path` will be filled in for `:product_id`. (For the reasons mentioned above, `line_items_path(product)` should yield the same result.) The `_url` and `_path` helpers are generated by the routes in your `config/routes.rb` file, so they already know which controller and action to use and you don't need to specify `:controller` or `:action` like you sometimes need to with `link_to`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your time and effort. Appreciate it tons

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Rails will automagically call id on product in this circumstance.

Comment: but why a hash? how does this hash produce a value? is there a reason behind syntax?

Comment: Yes, have you looked at how Rails routes work? This route will be defined with a parameter for the product_id -> your hash is saying "for the value of product id, use this product"

Comment: the book doesn't give out the routes yet at this point of the book. but i found it here ... https://github.com/kristianmandrup/awd-rails-4th-depot-app/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

is a message send, sending the message `line_items_path` to the implicit receiver `self`, passing `product_id: product` as the argument.

If the last argument to a message send is a `Hash` literal, it is allowed to leave off the curly braces, and if the key of a key-value-pair in a `Hash` literal is a `Symbol`, it can optionally be written as `sym: expr` instead of `:sym => expr`.

Alternatively, if the `line_items_path` method has been defined to have keyword parameters, `product_id: product` could also be passing `product` as the value for the `product_id` keyword argument.

(The two syntaxes are deliberately identical to allow for a smooth transition towards keyword arguments.)

Last but not least, `product` is a local variable, more precisely a parameter binding of the block.

Comment: All other currently existing answers are (primarily) about the semantics of Rails' routing, but the OP specifically only asked about the syntax and not the semantics.